Extracting elements of a array
I want to extract elements of a array, then store them in a new array and compare them to another array. The problem ist, that I don't want to extract elements in a order.
I used the .slice function for extracting elements in a order.
let winArray = [playerSymbol, playerSymbol, playerSymbol]
if (playingFielddArray.slice(0, 3).every(v => winArray.includes(v))) {
    // Do something }

This is working fine. This would be my try for elements that are not in order:
    let newArray = [playingFielddArray[0], playingFielddArray[4], playingFielddArray[8]]
    if(newArray.every(v => winArray.includes(v))){ // Do something }

But I don't like this solution. I would need to create many arrays and compare them.
Is there a function I can use for that?

How about writing a function? If you were more specific about the common use case, it would also be easier to point to some direction (or determine, whether .every(... .includes ...) is performant enough).

What's the logic you want to extract the elements by?

Basically I want to create a TicTacToe Game. This is my "gamefieldArray":
let playingFielddArray = [0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0,
                      0, 0, 0]

And then I want to check the possible "game Winning" conditions. But they are not all in order (as you all know TicTacToe I guess).

If this is a tictactoe game and you want to check if there is a winner you can write a function which loops 3 times and checks positions:
[i*3, i*3+1, i*3+2] // for horizontal fields
[i, i+3, i+6] // for vertical field
[i,i+4,i+8] // if i=0
[i, i+2, i+4] // if i=2

If these fields contains same icons/names/ids it's a match

Yes that will be working! Thank you.
